# C String Array Manipulaion

Tags: c, arrays, string, type-conversion

```
char input[INPUT_SIZE];  /*Holding user input globaly*/

char history[50][INPUT_SIZE]; /*Storing last 0 commands*/

void addToHistory()
{
  history[0] = input;
  printf("#: %s \n", history[0]);
}

 fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin) /*Using this to get the input*/
```

Im using the fgets to save the input, and then i want to be able to called the add to history function to save the current input to the first value in history but i keep getting the error messsgage...

" error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[512]’ from type ‘char *"
Ive tryed using &input , *input but its still the same..

I cant seem to solve this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array, you should copy to it:

```
memcpy(history[0], input, sizeof(history[0]));
```

Comment: Or use [`strcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcpy.html), which avoids copying unused bytes :)

Comment: @pmg - you're right, I missed some parts of the question, just saw the assignment :)